# Laravel 5.1: Query Builder Select Multi table and SUM result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

My code

```
DB::table('users_tb')->leftjoin('device_tb', 'device_tb.user_id', '=', 'users_tb.user_id')
->leftjoin('part_tb', 'device_tb.device_id', '=', 'part_tb.device_id')
->select('users_tb.user_name', DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(part_tb.id) FROM part_tb) AS counter"))
->where('users_tb.level', '>', 7)
->havingRaw("(SELECT COUNT(part_tb.id) FROM part_tb) > 0")
->groupBy('device_tb.device_id')
->orderBy('users_tb.user_name')
->get()->toArray();
```

My result:

```
Name1 - 3
Name1 - 4
Name1 - 3
Name2 - 11
Name2 - 2
```

How i can SUM counter? (with Query Builder/SQL query) Example:

```
Name1 - 10 (3+4+3)
Name2 - 13 (11 + 2)
```

Somebody help me, please!!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom array, I think your query array is same. You can write your code flowing way.

```
$arrs['Name1'] = array(
    3,4,3
 );
 $arrs['Name2'] = array(
    11,2
 ); 

$count_status = array();
 foreach($arrs as $index=>$arr){
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($arr as $key=>$arrss){      
        isset($arrs[$index]) ? $count_status[$index] = $sum+=$arrss : $sum = 0;
    }
    $allVal[$index] = implode('+',$arr);
 }
 foreach($count_status as $stKey=>$eachCount){
     echo $stKey.' - '.$eachCount.' ('.$allVal[$stKey].') <br>';
 }
```

Output for me

```
//Name1 - 10 (3+4+3) 
//Name2 - 13 (11+2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great idea. But, you can SUM result with Query Builder